# Android ListView Dividing columns with divider equally

Tags: android, listview, divider

I have a list view which contains of 3 columns.
I would like to use a divider to separate them equally in 3 parts.
For example

TEXT   |   TEXT   | TEXT

FACE   |   GFRt  |  FOEE

However when I use a divider it is looking like this

ABC| efef| fkejfe

dffewf| feffe| efie

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I am far away from android for a long time.

My XML CODE IS AS BELOW:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add your xml file here

Comment: help will always be given at hogwarts.But first post your xml :)

Comment: ok sir pls wait a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this layout to divide your views equally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel1"
    android:text="12345"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

 <View
    android:id="@+id/divider1"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel2"
    android:text="12345"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />


<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:text="12345"
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it is just dividing but not equally. It is just putting a divider at the side of textviews pretty much same with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider1"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />


<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />


    </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.